# ListView.addHeaderView have bug?

Tags: android, android-listview

I add to myListView header `TextView` and in `onItemClickListener` positions moves up, and header becomes clickable(his position now one), and list's item position +1 Why?

**Code.java**

```
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_text, null);        
    mMoviesList.addHeaderView(header);
```

**header_text.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <TextView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/_main_shadow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/after_top_bar_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/after_top_bar_margin_top"
                android:paddingBottom="5px"
                android:text="Показывают в кино"
                android:textColor="#898989"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`mMoviesList.addHeaderView(header, null, false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) instead.

Comment: it's help to me. and in onItemClickListener i add position-1

Answer (score 0):

In `onClickListener()` ignore if the position of click is 0. Just put:

```
if (position > 0) {
    // your operations
}
```